# I can't push my app to scalingo - I keep getting "Precompiling assets failed" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, deployment

I'm working on a small project on Rails (Rails 7.0.4.3), but I keep getting the same error. Here's what I see in the console:

```
Running: rake assets:precompile
rake aborted!
SassC::SyntaxError: Error: File to import not found or unreadable: index.
on line 1:1 of stdin
>> @import "index";
!     Precompiling assets failed.
!
!     An error occurred during buildpack compilation
 !   Error deploying the application
!   → Invalid return code from buildpack
```

That @index is a .scss file in my application.scss. Does anyone know why it's unreadable or rake can't find it?

I removed  gem "sassc-rails" from Gemfile, then ran bundle install, restarted the server. Nothing happened. I removed gem "Webpacker" and did the same routine (I saw it helped someone else). I added scss-rails back, also added gem 'bootstrap-sass', ran bundle install, then again, nothing. I'm really stumped. I'm still relatively new to Rails and any help would be appreciated!